# Can't see any page animations in GOOGLE TV ViewFlipper

Tags: android, viewflipper, android-animation, google-tv

I have an application that uses the ViewFlipper and the built in animation for PageIn and PageOut and I don't see any animations occurring on my GOOGE TV.  Phones and tablets all work, but animations are not showing on my GOOGLE TV logitech box or Sony GOOGLE TV box.

My app is a photo/video slideshow photo book type viewer, so we're using the resources of the device, but still have no issues on the phone.  I'm running a sony and a logitech and same results.

The same code base works perfectly on Honeycomb and the phone.  Has anyone else seen very jerky performance in your apps that do a ton of Bitmap decoding and usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that Hardware Acceleration isn't enabled in the current builds of Honeycomb for Google TV. That is the cause of the issue.

Comment: where did you get this information? One of the developer advocates for GoogleTV (Paul Saxman) has informed me that HW acceleration for GoogleTV is always on

Comment: Bhavya from GoogleTV team tested my app and told me so.

Comment: I got the update to my Sony Google TV and my animations all work perfectly now!!! No code to change, I love it!

Answer (score 0):

The sample code http://www.warriorpoint.com/blog/2009/05/26/android-switching-screens-in-an-activity-with-animations-using-viewflipper/ shows Page in/out animation on Sony devices. Are you doing something different on your side?

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, but this article doesn't address the issue on GOOGLE TV. My animations work on phones and tablets.

Answer (score 0):

Been working on a similar project on GoogleTV and it is now open-source:
https://github.com/elsewhat/com.elsewhat.android.slideshow

I use Gallery as the key component, but had performance problems on large screens with GoogleTV and the "swipe" transition Gallery uses. Been in touch with people from GoogleTV product management, and we were unable to find a solution for the root cause.

Ended up with combining the Gallery with a ViewAnimator to fake a fade-out/fade-in effect and performance is on longer an issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the animations on GTV need some time to warm up before they're ready to perform smoothly. Try putting a small delay at the beginning of your animation.

```
android:startOffset="1500"
```

It will kill your responsiveness, but that's acceptable for our purposes because we're using it during an automatic slideshow.

Comment: I am against making this kind of code adjustment as it kills everything I'm trying to do, which is have a timed animation play.